# What happened to the 'New Novel' trend? Did it live into the 21st century?

Tags: history-of-literature

I don't remember reading any novels written by 21st century authors similar to those of the 'New Novel' movement. Maybe Enjoe Toh counts, but his works are more sci-fi rather than 'pure' fiction. Did such an innovative style just disappear, or did it evolve into something else?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you explain a bit what you mean by 'New Novel'? I am familiar with the [Nouveau roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_roman), but that was a French literary movement.

Comment: @Tsundoku I'm referring to the Nouveau roman, I used 'New Novel' because Brittanica called it that way.

Comment: It seems to me that much of the philosophy behind *le nouveau roman* has been incorporated into the more experimental strains of literary fiction.

Comment: Robbe-Grillet seemed to continue with it, e.g. *Repetition* (2001), but unsurprisingly most of the original practitioners were dead by the 21st century. I think it's too vague a movement (many people claimed to be a part of it denied it) and too closely associated with a few main practitioners to really be a distinct style, although a lot of more recent experimental novelists (e.g. Tom McCarthy) probably show some influence of some of it. (Wikipedia is fairly shit for modern literature so not sure where's the best source.)